# Gridview row count property

Tags: asp.net, gridview

is there any property for gridview last page rows count in asp.net clientside

```
        GridView1.PageIndex = GridView1.PageCount - 1;
        var currentCount = (GridView1.PageIndex) * GridView1.PageSize +GridView1.Rows.Count;
        lblGridviewTotalCount.Text = currentCount.ToString();
```

Specifically i want the last page count

Thanks in advance

Comment: On clientside there is only one page. The html of the other pages is not rendered at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter user23.. wants count rows in last page not number of pages!

Comment: i want  to know the total records in gridview while paging is true

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: no got the wrong total....there

Answer (score 1):

For counting number of last page's rows,use this code:

```
int currentCount = GridView1.Rows.Count-((GridView1.PageCount-1) * GridView1.PageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `HiddenField` each time to store count of the current page and use this hiddenField in client side

remember you can always get number of rows in `gridview` (HTML Table) using javascript/jquery , like this `$('#grid_view_table_id tr').length`

Comment: yeah but i need to display the last page record count

Comment: @Bhanu storing row count of the last page , in a hidden field is just to make it available in client side , after that you can do what you want with this value in javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.hear you will get re-mender.That is your last page value.

```
int LastPageCount =Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows.Count) %  Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.PageSize)
```